# My react native app is slower and even slower with react navigation

Tags: react-native, performance, optimization, react-navigation, memoization

My react native app is slow. It takes about 5-6 seconds to render first screen of application. And navigation between screens is even worse.

- react-native: 0.71.3
- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs: 6.5.7
- @react-navigation/native: 6.1.6
- @react-navigation/stack: 6.3.16
- react-navigation/native-stack: 6.9.12

I’ve memoised almost every function in every screen and have seen no clear difference. Please help deployment is near and I’m getting anxious

This issue is prevalent on android

Comment: Cannot able to judge your application by just packages. I need to see the render method of your pages and wherever place you used either of ScrollView or Flatlist? also need to see where you set navigation container